# resizeBy not working and don't know why

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't my resize button resize the window that my "create window" -button creates? I have searched and none of the answers I've found work. I'm all out of ideas now. Please help!

```
<div id="windowbuttons">
<button onclick="openWin()">Create window</button>
<button onclick="resizeWin()">Resize window</button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin()
{
myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com","", "width=100,height=100");
}

function resizeWin()
{
myWindow.resizeBy(250,250);
myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</div>
```

And it does work correctly when I delete the url from window.open, so that it looks like

```
function openWin()
{
myWindow = window.open("","", "width=100,height=100");
}
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myWindow;

function openWin()
{
    myWindow = window.open("http://localhost","", "width=100,height=100");
}

function resizeWin()
{
    myWindow.resizeBy(250,250);
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

```html
<div id="windowbuttons">
    <button onclick="openWin()">Create window</button>
    <button onclick="resizeWin()">Resize window</button>
</div>
```

You are opening http://google.com in a new window and then you are trying to resize http://google.com from your script, which is restricted. In order to work this, your child window must reside on the same host and port as of your parent window